# wordpress theme with base64 in css?

Tags: css, wordpress, base64

I started working on a wordpress theme for a client that has some strange css. I uploaded it to codeviewer.

[View Code](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:17da)

I know this is potentially dangerous. How can I found out for sure?

Thanks!
Zeem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, It is a special url code called URI

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme